# ShowWindow()...mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am calling one dialog box from another.....before calling 2nd dialog box i am hiding the 1st dialog box using ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) and after finishing the operation on 2nd dialog box i destroy it....now when the control comes back to the function i am using ShowWindow(SW_SHOW) to show the 1st dialog again but it remains hidden..can anybody help me how to show it again????

EX:

```
Funcn(){

    ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);//hide the dialog box 1st

    SecondDlg var;//Class variable of 2nd dialog box

    var.DoModal();//call the 2nd dialog box

    ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);//after executing this statement the dialog still remains hidden...how to show it??

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to call ShowWindow(SW_RESTORE) instead of SW_SHOW?